# Split one gravity form in two sections (using elementor)

Tags: jquery, css, elementor, gravityforms

is possible to split gravity form in two sections. so I have elementor column left with some info and the right column is part of form. Below these two columns need to be the second part of the form which is full width. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Icon boxes to html block in form solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).